# jquery / css fill circle image from top to bottom

Tags: jquery, css

Ive been trying to achieve a similar effect that can be seen in the portfolio section of this site: http://www.richdean.co.uk/ when you hover over an image. I honestly have been trying to figure out how he did this and it's probably pretty simple, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Miles

Comment: That’s simply using `border-radius` to get the circle-shape … the rest is just run-of-the-mill `transition` triggered via `:hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way: **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kewix/3/edit)**

```
<div class="circle" id="circ1">
  <div>+<br>VIEW PROJECT</div>
</div>

<div class="circle" id="circ2">
  <div class="cover">+<br>VIEW PROJECT</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle{
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
  background:transparent none no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#circ1{
  background-image: url('bg1.jpg');
}
#circ2{
  background-image: url('bg2.jpg');
}

.circle > div{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  padding:100px 0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  top:-250px;
  background:#fff;
  transition: top 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
}
.circle:hover > div{
  top:0;
}
```

The basic idea is to have a `relative positioned` round element with an inner `absolute pos.` element initially positioned at some -top value.

The round element needs the `overflow:hidden` property in order to hide-contain the inner white element.

For the animations you can than use JS / jQuery or CSS3

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! For someone reason I thought it would be far more complicated than this. You are awesome thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a circle from a div using `border-radius`:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
}
```

Then add `overflow:hidden` to the circle. Make a `div` that is a child to the circle, and set its `top` offset to `-100%` so that it is out of sight and above the circle. Use jquery's `.animate()` to move the top orientation to `0%` so that it fills the circle. You could also use [css transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) to move the inner div down using `:hover`.